# Oracle select top N rows based on Values

Tags: sql, oracle

Say if I have a table with the following column,

```
Marks
60
80
70
90
95
90
70
```

I need to select all the rows with a mark in the top 4, ie. in this case, >=70 and 6 rows should be returned.

I'm not sure how to do this, can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: There are so many variations of this question already on this site.

Comment: Plus this very interesting site.  http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Marks FROM (
  SELECT Marks, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS MarksRank
  FROM yourtable
) WHERE MarksRank <= 4
```

Comment: I believe you need to use RANK() not DENSE_RANK() because you want the top four distinct Mark values which should return 6 rows in the example.

Comment: @tylert using `RANK()` will only give you 4 records on this case.

Comment: Exactly - with `RANK()` the ranks will be assigned as follows: 95=1, 90=2, 90=2, 80=4, 70=5, etc. Note how it goes from 90=2 to 80=4: 90 is tied for second, so 80 drops down to 4th place. `DENSE_RANK` will get rid of the gaps in the ranking: 95=1, 90=2, 90=2, 80=3, 70=4, etc.

Comment: I looked again and I see why that's correct -- and I had misunderstood how DENSE_RANK() differed from RANK()